# What is a good model for heavy multiclass problem and small number of (textual) features?

Tags: classification, natural-language, multi-class

I have a data set with a small number of textual features (less than 10) and a response variable with a lot of classes (~100).

Is there any recommendation for models that are powerful for this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The number of features does not matter as long as the predictive power of the features is high enough. For example, if the data set is a collection of news articles, one feature contains tags and the response variable is the category, one can expect a reasonable model quality (assuming descriptive tags, of course).

On the other hand, if the predictive power is poor, no model will help (or the difference between models is negligible).

I had good results with Stochastic Gradient Boosted Tree in the past (although with a lot of samples). Some more ideas can be found here: [Off the shelf tool for multi-label classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12907/off-the-shelf-tool-for-multi-label-classification/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Also I have a question that some of the classes labels might not even occur in the dataset however they might occur in new dataset. How could model include this kind of information?

Comment: A model cannot predict classes it has not seen before. One can work around the problem by combining classes on a higher level (hierarchical classification) or treat model prediction as "I don't know" if the confidence in the predicted class is to small, so that a human can deal with it approriately.